# Recursive string compare in Python

Tags: python, django

I have to compare 2 lists of strings fetched from the database and from a CSV file respectively.

The data objects could vary in length.

### The condition

**if obj1 >= obj2** the perform the code.
but since the data can vary in length I have to hard code every possibility according to the length of the objects, which is tiring and wrong.

According to the code if a obj1 length is greater than obj2 length then perform the program.

Can you please tell me a way where I can compare a string of length 8 and length 4 (example numbers) without hard coding it through if else. I believe this is achievable through while loop. Which is sadly my weak point.
and this comparison goes until the first character is reached and when WHILE reaches 0 it breaks.

Meaning if I get an object of length 2 and the other object length is 3, How can I perform recursive compressing of the objects through while loop.

HELP would be greatly appreciated.

I hope you get the question.

```py
def LCR():
    dest = Destination.objects.values_list('dest_num', flat=True)
# This method turn the fetched data into a list. Example
#['1233','4412','23135','123']
    rates = {}
    ratelist = {}



    csv_file = open(r'.\adoc.csv')



    data_set = csv_file.read().decode("UTF-8")
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=str(u",")):
        rates[column[0]] = column[1]
#Example data
#['8523654','754','4563']



    for desNum in dest:
        desNum = str(desNum)
        # print type(desNum)


        for venNum, venValue in rates.items():
            venlen = len(venNum)
            deslen = len(desNum)
            if venlen >= deslen:



                if desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-1] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-3]:
                    print (venNum)
                    print (desNum)
                    # print "Works well"
                    # print ('====================')

                    ratelist[venNum] = venValue




                elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-3] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-4]:

                    # ratelist[venNum] = venValue
                    print (venNum)
                    print (desNum)


                elif desNum[:-1] == desNum[:-3] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-5]:

                    # ratelist[venNum] = venValue
                    print (venNum)
                    print (desNum)



                elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-5]:

                    # ratelist[venNum] = venValue
                    print (venNum)
                    print (desNum)


                elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-5] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-6]:
                    # ratelist[venNum] = venValue
                    print (venNum)
                    print (desNum)
            else:
                print "LENGTH ERROR"
    print ratelist
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to know if `venNum` starts with `desNum`?

Comment: starts from the end side yes. But since the length could be different I can't use -5 or -3 etc like that. Or can I?

Comment: You can just do `if venNum.startswith(desNum)`  rather than all of those nested if statements

Comment: I have to make sure the sequence matches.
 if [:-1] == [:-1] and [:-2] == [:-2] and [:-3]==[:-3] . . . . .

Something like that

Comment: `venNum.startswith(desNum)` is exactly doing that.

Comment: @blues [Startswith](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith)

Comment: What is the problem? That it does not check the end as well? Just reverse both strings and do the check again. `venNum[::-1].startswith(desNum[::-1])` to check if the ends match

Comment: The program works fine. But I want to do all of this using **While Loop**

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't understand what exactly is the question, I guess you want to check one of these conditions.

If you would like to know if `string1` contains `string2` you could do:

```py
if string2 in string1:
    # Do what you want to do
```

`string2 in string1` will return True if `string1` contains `string2`.

Or

```py
if string1.find(string2) != -1:
    # Do what you want to do
```

`string1.find(string2)` will return the index `string2` occurs in `string1`. If `string2` couldn't be found, it returns `-1`.

If you would like to know if `string1` starts or ends with `string2` you could do:

```py
if string1.startswith(string2):
    # Do what you want to do
```

```py
if string1.endswith(string2):
    # Do what you want to do
```

So in your case `string1` would be equal to the `venNum` and `string2` would be equal to the `desNum`. You could implement it like this:

```py
if venNum in desNum:
    # Do what you want to do
```

```py
if venNum.find(desNum) != -1:
    # Do what you want to do
```

```py
if venNum.startswith(desNum):
    # Do what you want to do
```

```py
if venNum.endswith(desNum):
    # Do what you want to do
```